# Decimal format incorrect after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project using jquery, and I applied a manual method to deal with decimal format, for example I display numbers with two decimals with two floating digits, and for making numbers more readable, I use comma between thousands, it's working fine, but when the form is submitted, there are two zeros that're been added, for example :
 2500.00 before submitting is displayed 2,500.00, I created a function that removes the comma, on the submit event, using firebug, I'm making sure that the comma is remmoved and I got : 2500.00, BUT when data are displayed in the show view/page, I got 250000.00
see ?? there are two zeros added, I don't know how, there is my code :

```
$("#stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_submit").click( function() {
        $('input[id$="prixLignefacturefournisseur"]').each(function(){
            idprix = $(this).attr('id');
            prix = document.getElementById(idprix);
            if (document.getElementById(idprix).value ){
                var prixv = document.getElementById(idprix).value.replace(",","");
                document.getElementById(idprix).value = prixv;
                console.log('prixv : ',prixv);
            }
        });
        $('input[id$="totalLignefacturefournisseur"]').each(function(){
            idtotal = $(this).attr('id');
            total = document.getElementById(idtotal);
            if (document.getElementById(idtotal).value ){
                var totalv = document.getElementById(idtotal).value.replace(",","");
                document.getElementById(idtotal).value = totalv;
                console.log('total : ',totalv);
            }
        });
    });
```

Note: I working with Symfony2.

plz any idea, how to deal with this kind of provlems ??
thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: This is a pure HTML/JS or is there a roundtrip to a server ? I ask this, because you have probably a French locale and that might interfere with ,/.

Comment: thanks, yeah I'm working with symfony2, and the field is typed as decimal

Comment: then you should check what sends/receives Symfony. The culprit is may be not Javascript ...Voilà

Comment: I followed the request and found that the number is sent to the server like this : 2000.00 is sent as 2000

Comment: So this is correct. And the value sent by the server is correct as well ?

Comment: Yeah I found where was the problem I lastly modified an attribute in the formType class, changed the type of the field to money type giving it precision of two Zeros, thanks a lot for trying to help me, I apreciate it maan !!